# How to fix IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on generating a simple sine function defined over the range [0,1] as shown below. However I got an index error when assigning `function[i]`. I tried to set `x_n = int(x_n)` as some questions with the same error suggest but that only creates further errors.

```
import numpy as np

function = np.zeros(20)
x_n=np.arange(0,1,0.05) #[0,1]

for i in x_n:
    function[i] = np.sin(2*np.pi*i)
```

Note `x_n` has a step of 0.05 because I need to generate 20 values ranging from 0 to 1.

Comment: Look at the `i` that's used you use as index.  Does that explain the error message.   A float like 0.05 cannot be used as an index!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create array zero and insert numbers in this, you can do this with vectorizing magic in `NumPy` like below:

```
x_n=np.arange(0,1,0.05) #[0,1]
np.sin(x_n*np.pi*2)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.00000000e+00,  3.09016994e-01,  5.87785252e-01,  8.09016994e-01,
        9.51056516e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.51056516e-01,  8.09016994e-01,
        5.87785252e-01,  3.09016994e-01,  1.22464680e-16, -3.09016994e-01,
       -5.87785252e-01, -8.09016994e-01, -9.51056516e-01, -1.00000000e+00,
       -9.51056516e-01, -8.09016994e-01, -5.87785252e-01, -3.09016994e-01])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that i is a float, while array indices are ints.
You should change your code to

```py
import numpy as np

function = np.zeros(20)
x_n=np.arange(0,1,0.05) #[0,1]

for i in x_n:
    function[int(i*20)] = np.sin(2*np.pi*i)
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic Python iteration tool is `enumerate`.  With this you can iterate on an array of floats, and still get a sequential integer index.

```
In [16]: arr = np.zeros(20)
    ...: x_n=np.arange(0,1,0.05) #[0,1]
    ...: 
    ...: for i,v in enumerate(x_n):
    ...:     arr[i] = np.sin(2*np.pi*v)
    ...: 
In [17]: arr
Out[17]: 
array([ 0.00000000e+00,  3.09016994e-01,  5.87785252e-01,  8.09016994e-01,
        9.51056516e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.51056516e-01,  8.09016994e-01,
        5.87785252e-01,  3.09016994e-01,  1.22464680e-16, -3.09016994e-01,
       -5.87785252e-01, -8.09016994e-01, -9.51056516e-01, -1.00000000e+00,
       -9.51056516e-01, -8.09016994e-01, -5.87785252e-01, -3.09016994e-01])
```

An alternative is to iterate with `for i in range(len(x_n)):`, but `enumerate` is clearer.

But you don't need to iterate (in python) at all:

```
In [18]: np.sin(2*np.pi*x_n)
Out[18]: 
array([ 0.00000000e+00,  3.09016994e-01,  5.87785252e-01,  8.09016994e-01,
        9.51056516e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.51056516e-01,  8.09016994e-01,
        5.87785252e-01,  3.09016994e-01,  1.22464680e-16, -3.09016994e-01,
       -5.87785252e-01, -8.09016994e-01, -9.51056516e-01, -1.00000000e+00,
       -9.51056516e-01, -8.09016994e-01, -5.87785252e-01, -3.09016994e-01])
```